# Change bytes to GB only

Tags: php

How can I change a value of bytes to GB only and not to KB,MB. 
I only want the value in GB.

I need this for chartjs

I have this code so far

```
function formatBytesToGB($size)
{
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
    $factor = floor((strlen($size) - 1) / 3);
    return number_format($size / pow(1024, $factor), 2) ." ". $units[$factor];
}
```

Comment: You have that backwards and I want GB, Gigabytes like I mentioned

Comment: `$GB = $size * .000000001;`

Comment: if you want only in `GB` then don't use `$units` : [check this exmaple](https://eval.in/995415)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the result in GB

```
$size / pow(1024, 3);
```